# For loop with different inputs

Tags: c++, for-loop

please see my code below and let me know what I'm not seeing. I've tried almost everything to make it work and nothing yet.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

```
for (double c = c1; c <= c2; c = c + i)
{
    cout << "Enter the lowest temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> c1;
    cout << "Enter the highest temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> c2;
    cout << "Enter the desired increment in temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> i;

    f = ((9 / 5) * c) + 32;

    cout << "When C is " << c << " degrees Celsius, the temperature in Fahrenheit will be: " << f << " degrees." << endl;

    cin.get();
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What error do you get ? which are the type of `c1`, `c2`, `i` ?

Comment: I'm getting this error for c1 and c2                                                           error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'c1'

Comment: Why do you ask parameter of the loop not before the loop instead of inside the loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the input in the wrong part of the code.

`c1` and `c2` were probably never assigned before the loop, and your logic as reflected in the codedoesn't seem to match your intentions as it changes the loop limit every time.

Also, note using `9.0` instead of `9` to get a `double` result and not an integer.

See full example here https://ideone.com/Uj974z.

```
int main() {

    double c1, c2, i, f;

    cout << "Enter the lowest temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> c1;
    cout << "Enter the highest temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> c2;
    cout << "Enter the desired increment in temperature: " << endl;
    cin >> i;

    for (double c = c1; c <= c2; c = c + i)
    {
        f = ((9.0 / 5) * c) + 32;
        cout << "When C is " << c << " degrees Celsius, the temperature in Fahrenheit will be: " << f << " degrees." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You were right! I did not look at it that way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 9/5 returns 1. You should write 9.0/5.